# formula field challenge on trailhead showing issue

Tags: formula-field, trailhead

In Trailhead "Improve Data Quality for Your Sales and Support Teams" Trailmixes step"

[image]

I have follow all the instruction and even i have check opportunity object field "Annual Revenue" and set visible to all profile as well as on account object field **"Annual Revenue"** and set visible to all profile and both fields are showing on record details page respectively.

But when i have check challenge it is throwing error

> "Step not yet complete in Trailhead Playground 2 Formula in custom
> field 'Account Annual Revenue' is not correct. Check the
> instructions."

[image]

Comment: Let me know if you have already done this - Click on 'Set Field-Level Security' button on the page shown in the screenshot, check the 'Visible' checkbox to make the field visible for all profiles. Save

Comment: I have already done this step